# What is the term for an exact value in an otherwise continuous distribution?

Tags: distributions

For some continuous quantities (e.g. daily rainfall at a certain location), there is one exact value that occurs often (in the case of daily rainfall that's the value of zero: there are days on which it does not rain). However, for continuous distributions, the chance of finding some other exact number (say 3.2000... mm) is zero. I remember from statistics class that an exact number that does occur more often has a name. But I can't remember it! Can anyone help?